# How can I access the value of this event in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dom-events

I would like to be able to access the value of an input, normally I usually retrieve it with `event.target.value` but this time it is not possible since the `event.target` path throws me a li element:

[image]

It is a component of the material UI library:

```
<MenuItem
  onClick={handleItemValue}
  value={"VALUE TO RECOVER"}
>
 Option Text
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` prop is usually used to set the value, not to read it. I would recommend the `useRef` hook if this is a functional component:

```js
let menuItemRef = React.useRef(null);

<MenuItem
   ref={menuItemRef}
>
     Option Text
</MenuItem>
```

If you need to get the text contained within the element on click, you can use `innerText` like so:

```js
<MenuItem
   ref={menuItemRef}
   onClick={()=>console.log(menuItemRef.current.innerText)}
>
     Option Text
</MenuItem>
```

Not sure what you want to do with the value on click, but this will log it to the console. Basically, you can find the string in an element like `<li>` or `<p>` by creating a ref and then calling `refName.current.innerText`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Is it possible to access the ref value with the click event?

Comment: I have updated the solution above, hopefully that's what you were looking for :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know this method, this can give me several solutions.

Answer (score 1):

here an example for you:

```
const handleItemValue = (value) => {
   //you can access to `value`
}

<MenuItem
   onClick={() => handleItemValue("VALUE TO RECOVER")}
>
  Option Text
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will have to think about a solution well, thank you!